# google api client is connected return false

Tags: android, google-api-client

in my code the google api client returns the false value even it is being connected

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG,"btn is clicked");
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            Log.i(TAG,"build google api completed");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            Log.i(TAG,"client conneted");
            Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));


        }
});

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the code for ConnectionCallbacks and ConnectionFailedListener? And perhaps print out some information from them.

Answer (score 9):

`mGoogleApiClient.connect();` is not a synchronous operation - that's why you set up a `addConnectionCallbacks(this)` when building your `GoogleApiClient`.

You have to wait for the [onConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onConnected(android.os.Bundle)) callback before `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()` will return `true` and you can use the `GoogleApiClient`.

Comment: Hi quick question. I've setup a callback to print a message when onConnected() is triggered. After that, I've setup a button to print "mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()", however it is still printing false, even after the onConnected() callback was successful. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

use this method to return true for you.

```
public RequestAssync connect(){
    SystemStatus ss = Android.request.connection();
    if(ss.isConnect()){
        return ss.getStatus();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```